# enterprise wiki search results not returning friendly urls

Tags: search, managed-metadata, enterprise-wiki

I set up an enterprise wiki, with the pages set to hide physical urls from search (show friendly URLs):

```
http://infostore/sites/testWiki/human/boromir
```

When I search for a page name, it only returns the `allitems.aspx` page as a result, rather than the actual page itself.

The page *is* indexed in the content source logs, and the result source is based on 'Local Sharepoint Sites', with a filter based on the path.

I have another page with multiple aliases:

```
http://infostore/sites/testWiki/pippin
http://infostore/sites/testWiki/hobbit/pippin
```

The first result shows up in search results, but not the second. I want the first to be hidden, and the second show up.